# Matrix times an unknown matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am a first-year student learning linear algebra, and this is the first time for me to learn matrices.
From the quiz for our unit of study, I found two questions that I do not understand how to do:

> 1. \begin{equation}
>      \begin{bmatrix}
>        -9 & 7 \\ -2 & -1
>      \end{bmatrix} X +
>      \begin{bmatrix}
>        -4 & -2 \\ 9 & 6
>      \end{bmatrix} =
>      \begin{bmatrix}
>        9 & -3 \\ 9 & -7
>      \end{bmatrix} X.
>    \end{equation}
> 2. \begin{equation}
>      \begin{bmatrix}
>        5 & -3 \\ -4 & 0
>      \end{bmatrix}
>      \begin{bmatrix}
>        \bbox[2px, white, border:1px solid black]{\color{white}{\Rule{0.8em}{1em}{0.1em}}{\tt -5/12}} &
>        \bbox[2px, white, border:1px solid black]{\color{white}{\Rule{0.8em}{1em}{0.1em}}{\tt 1/4}} \\
>        \bbox[2px, white, border:1px solid black]{\color{white}{\Rule{2em}{1em}{0.1em}}{\tt 1/3}} &
>        \bbox[2px, white, border:1px solid black]{\color{white}{\Rule{2em}{1em}{0.1em}}{\tt 0}}
>      \end{bmatrix} =
>      \begin{bmatrix}
>        1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
>      \end{bmatrix}.
>    \end{equation}

(The answers in the box is the wrong answer that I first wrote)

Can somebody give a hint for that? Thank you beforehand.

---Edit:--- Attempts

For question1: I successfully convert the question into a AX=B form. I got a hint saying that I should continue with the REF method, but I am not sure how to do it.

For question2: **Solved!**, using the inverse of the matrix given.

Still need help for question1, but I am so happy that I am making progress with the help of you guys!

Comment: **Hint for question 1** Can you rewrite this equation in the form $AX=b$? If yes, you can use the standard Gauss algorithm (also called row reduction stuff) to solve the system.

Comment: **Hint for question 2** Think about inverses of matrices, do you know how to calculate them?

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are certain rules that are followed on this site for asking a good question. This is certainly not a homework site.One needs to share what effort one has put into solving the problem and where exactly is she or he stuck. If one is having difficulty in the very beginning, this means the best approach would be to go back to the basics and revise and review the basic fundamentals involved behind the topic related to the question.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: Sorry for the improper format of the question. So for the question one, do I take the put the ones with X together? And calculate the inverse of the matrix given for question 2?

Comment: I tried to convert it to AX=B for question 1, and I succeed. But I don't know what to do next as B is a matrix as well

Comment: @naveendankal Nice catch for my typo in the first question.  However, the second question is meant to be a question with input boxes to be filled in.  If you [edit] them away, others won't understand what's the question.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Sorry for the improper format again. I edited it now, is it better?

Comment: @Mathematician42 Hi, I tried to convert question 1 to AX=B, and I succeed, but I don't know what to do next..? because they are both matrix?

Comment: Sorry Iris that my [edit] crash with yours.  I wasn't aware that we are working on editing at the same time.  Why don't considering adding some attempt for both questions?

Comment: @GNUSupporter Sorry for expanding the comments. I don't have enough reputation to make it a chat. Is it better to read now?

Comment: Left multiply $A^{-1}$ on both sides and *type your numerical results for $X=A^{-1}B$* for the context.  Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @GNUSupporter thanks for the hint! I am catching a train now and will have a go when I get home, and I will let you know if I succeed! Big thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 above can be written as:  [A]X + [B] = [C]X

This can be re-written as [A-C]X = [-B]

Then assuming that the matrix [A-C] is non-singular, one can pre-multiply both sides by the inverse matrix $[A-C]^{-1}$ to find the value of the vector X.

For the second question you need to revise how to calculate the inverse of a 2x2 matrix.